# Best practice with lifetime of IMongoDatabase object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, database, mongodb

I'm brand new to NoSQL and I have a question. I've created a DatabaseHandler that allows me to grab a collection globally across my solution. I then noticed that I'm using 1 instance of IMongoDatabase for the entire lifetime of my application, is this correct?

Obviously coming form a MySQL background I'm used to using and opening a new connection on each call to DatabaseHandler

I'm just asking for someone to check if this is okay, as I'm really new and It's sort of confusing me.

```
internal sealed class DatabaseHandler : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public IMongoDatabase MongoDatabase;

    public DatabaseHandler()
    {
        var config = Program.Server.ConfigHandler;

        var databaseHost = config.GetValue("database.hostname");
        var databasePort = config.GetValue("database.port");

        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
        {
            Server = new MongoServerAddress(databaseHost, databasePort.ToInteger()),
            ServerSelectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        });

        MongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(config.GetValue("database.name"));

        var isMongoLive = MongoDatabase.RunCommandAsync((Command<BsonDocument>)"{ping:1}").Wait(1000);

        if (!isMongoLive)
        {
            Logger.Error("We couldn't establish a connection with the database.");
        }
    }

    public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string name)
    {
        return MongoDatabase.GetCollection<T>(name);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MongoDatabase.D
    }
}
```

Comment: I've always let the IoC container do all the wiring/creation/disposing of the collections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET best practices for MongoDB connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194047/net-best-practices-for-mongodb-connections)